# create all missing folders automatically on a given path

Tags: php, filesystems

I get some rows from mysql table
And want to put data from column `story` to a new-creating `.txt` file inside file-system
And gettint error - some folders in path - dont exists
Is there a way to create all missing folders automatically and finally create `.txt` file ?

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $path = $row['pt'] . "/" . $row['title'] . ".txt";
    if(!is_file($path)){
        fopen($path, "w");
        file_put_contents($path, $row['story']);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anant-Alivetodie - I already know that folders don't exists, there is no need to check. I just need the way to create them automatically from the given path

Comment: the link has that answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use php mkdir - [mkdir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    $path = $row['pt'] . "/" . $row['title'] . ".txt";
// make the folder, u can check if the folder exist, if not create it  
   mkdir($row['pt'] , 0777, true);
// put content
    if(!is_file($path)){
        fopen($path, "w");
        file_put_contents($path, $row['story']);
    }
}
```